# Can the On-Shell Scheme be used for QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics

I am reading a textbook on QFT and it mentions that the on-shell scheme cannot be used for QCD.

Could someone explain the on-shell renormalization scheme in a bit more detail, plus why QCD cannot be used in this scheme?  Intuitively, I understand that it is something to do with the fact that the constant for the running coupling is small at high energies and large at low energies, but could someone quantify this and explain in a bit more detail how exactly this asymptotic freedom means that QCD fails to fit into the on-shell scheme?

Further Information: I've looked up some lecture notes on QED/QCD and seen that the on-shell scheme does not contain parameters (whereas in other renormalization schemes, the mass of an electron or the coupling constant can depend on the renormalization scale).  However, in QCD it is known that the running coupling constant depends on energy, being small at high energies and large at low energies, as I said.  In QED, the coupling constant has an experimentally determined value which can be defined in the on-shell scheme, but in QCD it is shown by experiment to depend on energy, hence it cannot be defined to have one value and we cannot use the on-shell scheme for QCD (or at least, not at large distances with low energies/moment): correct me if this is wrong or needs more detail.

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: Maggiore 'Modern Introduction to QFT' pg. 248: 'At large distances...the theory [QCD] becomes non-perturbative' ie. meaning that the gluon field cannot be renormalized in the same scheme as QED where this does not happen.  But I am just asking for a bit more detail.

Comment: On-shell amounts to fixing "physical" values of couplings from scattering experiments at low energy. QCD confines at low energy – perturbative expansion breaks down. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I think that's pretty much the conclusion I came to in my post?